# AWS Architecture for Server->Worker

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, web-worker

I don't know how to setup my Architecture on AWS right.

Here is what i want to have:

A user can generate Queries and send them to a Webserver, which delegate this Queries to a specific Worker. This Worker starts a big process which can take a lot of time and produces output. This output should be readable for the User. Also it should be possible to cancel a running Process. This is a little bit tricky because there are more than just one Worker at a time. So i need something like a Broadcast to all.

I was thinking about ElasticBeanstalk but i don't see how to get the output to the user and also the cancle thing.

I hope someone can give me i tipp what is a good way to build this in AWS.

Comment: Read Lambda, Beanstalk, SQS, you need to put together these components/

Answer (score 0):

SQS + S3 + EC2 in Autoscaling group is probably what you're going for.

Take a look at [one of the AWS reference architectures](http://media.amazonwebservices.com/architecturecenter/AWS_ac_ra_batch_03.pdf) for such scenarios.

[image]